# Discord bot can't load data from attachment

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

I want to load data from a message.
I looked on the internet and i found that :

```js
if (message.attachments) {

       let attachment = message.attachments.first;
                    download(attachment.url);
                                
                    var myData = fs.readFileSync(attachment.filename);
                    data = JSON.parse(myData);

        }
```

But download() doesn't exist.
I didn't find other way to do that.

What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you found that piece of code, but it may be a little bit outdated.

You can use [`MessageAttachment.attachment`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageAttachment?scrollTo=attachment) in combination with [`fs.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) or [`fs.readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options)

You can try to write something like this:

```
if (message.attachments) {
  let file = message.attachments.first(); //this is the attchment you choose to use
  let data = fs.readFileSync(file.attachment); //this reads the attachment & returns the data
  //then you can parse it or use it however you want
}
```

Let me know if something doesn't work or if you have any further question

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
at loadDataFromMessage (/app/main.js:2314:29)
at Client.bot.on.message (/app/main.js:180:9)

Thank you for your fast help but it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

I guess it could be this, it downloads for example the url `https://example.com/image.png`  to `image.png` :

```
const path = require("path");
const https = require("https");

let download = function(url) {
    let filename = path.basename(url);
    let file = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
    let request = https.get(url, function(response) {
        response.pipe(file);
        file.on('finish', function() {
            file.close();
            });
        file.on('error', function(err) {
            fs.unlink(filename);
            console.error(err);
            });
        });
    };
```